# Simple java ticketing system in netbeans

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

We are required to complete a simple ticketing system for a local cinema in netbeans and I'm stumped on two problems.

> Problem 1 is as part of the output, is once you have selected ticket type + quantity, there needs to be an output "you are purchasing X number of tickets at Y quantity"
>
> Problem 2 is the seniors ticket needs to be at a cost of $32.50 and I cannot seem to find a workaround for allowing a calculation to be made using a decimal figure. I debugged and it seemed to change the number to an integer, which then would not calculate correctly. Help!

```
package ticketingsystem;

import java.io.*;
public class ticketingsystem
{
     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
     {
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String order,again;
         int quantity,price1=0,price2=0, price3=0,loop1=0,quantity1,quantity2=0;

         System.out.println("  ");  

         System.out.println("Welcome to the cinemas!");

         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("The cinema has the following options");
         System.out.println(" ");
         System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 yrs)");
         System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ yrs)");
         System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)");

         do{
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print("Enter your option: ");
            order=br.readLine();
            if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                price1=18;
            } else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                price1=36;
            }   
            else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                price1= (int) 32.5;
            }   

            System.out.print("Enter the number of tickets: ");
            quantity1= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            quantity2=quantity1+quantity2;

            price2=price1*quantity2;   
            System.out.println("You are purchasing " int (order=br) " tickets at" (quantity1);

            System.out.print("Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : ");
            again=br.readLine();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                loop1=loop1+1;
            else loop1=loop1-100;
      } while (loop1==1);    

     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.println("Total Price           : "+price2);   

 }
}
```

Comment: `double price1 = 0.0`. If `BigDecimal` was treated, that is the class of choice.

Answer (score 5):

Hi would suggest to make the following changes.

First rename price2 to totalPrice and change it to a double:

`double totalPrice;`

I would create an enum class for TicketType, where you can also assign the price1 value:

```
enum TicketType {
  child(18), adult(36), senior(32.5);

  TicketType(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  private double price;

  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }
}
```

You can now change you main method to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String order, again;
    int quantity = 0;
    double totalPrice;
    TicketType ticketType; // add the enum to the method

    System.out.println("  ");

    System.out.println("Welcome to the cinemas!");

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("The cinema has the following options");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 yrs)");
    System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ yrs)");
    System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)");

    do {
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.print("Enter your option: ");
      order = br.readLine();

      //use a switch case instead of the if else pattern
      switch (order.toLowerCase()) {
        case "1":
          ticketType = TicketType.child;
          break;

        case "3":
          ticketType = TicketType.senior;
          break;

        default:
          ticketType = TicketType.adult;
          break;
      }

      System.out.print("Enter the number of tickets: ");
      quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

      totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity;
      // %s will be replaced with the string value of ticketType, %.2f means it will be replaced with a decimal, round to decimals 
      System.out.printf("You are purchasing %s tickets at %.2f \n", ticketType, ticketType.getPrice());

      System.out.print("Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : ");
      again = br.readLine(); 
    }
    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.printf("Total Price           : $%.2f \n", totalPrice);
  }
```

You can use the [`System.out.printf()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf) to format messages you print to the console

Comment: @Gavin i moved the price to the Enum. Thanks for the suggestion! I did not quite understand how you would want to remove the switch-stament though? Move it to the Enum??

Comment: I don't think you actually can in this case as the `switch` is being used to determine the user input.  I let my default response to seeing a `switch` in OO code get the better of me :)

Comment: Not a fan of using `double` to represent Money, but in this case `BigDecimal` might be over kill, so on balance I am up voting.

Comment: Thanks :). I agree double is usually to imprecise to represent money. In this case the precision loss is neglect-able i think though :).

Comment: Cool thanks for that! It seems to calculate well. But it seems to have produced another problem.. After putting in one order of tickets (i.e. 2 child tickets at $18 each), if you select Y to continue the loop should reset to the start of the method, but it seems to start halfway through and no longer calculates multiple ticket prices... It did originally and the int loop should allow it to loop back using the answer but I'm stumped again unfortunately!

Comment: @Captain_Stag updated the code.  I think you should change `if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        loop1 = loop1 + 1;` to `if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        loop1 = 1;` and change `quantity2 = quantity1 + quantity2;

      totalPrice = ticketType.getPrice() * quantity2;` to
      `totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity1;` you can delete quantity2 i think

Comment: @Captain_Stag now that i think about it, you can also remove the `int loop1` and put the `again.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` in the `while()` evaluation brackets. I updated the answer. Ask me if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for helping Stephen! Yes I'm still a little stuck... It seems if you want to reloop the main menu, it continues resetting the loop at 'enter your option' when there is no reference to that point, and it does not continue looping

Answer (score 2):

On the price1 value, you are losing some precision by storing it as an int.

In Java, the int is rounded (to floor) to values without the decimal point precision. For this purpose, you'll want to use float or double to retain your cent value.

Also, you may find the [`java.text.NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/class-use/NumberFormat.html) class useful for the Currency handling.